Jupyter server failed
Pop up error:
Run Error

Jupyter server process failed to start Resolved value for exe path is null

I have changed nothing in my jupyter project, but when I reload my IDE I receive this error every time I attempt to run a notebook.I tried using different interpreters but this did not work. What can be causing it?

Are you using dataspell?

Nope, just regular pycharm professional
